# ScrollView in a NavigationView with a .navigationTitle presented in a .sheet : animation glitch

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiscrollview, swiftui-navigationview

The problem is very simple.
I would like a `ScrollView` with a navigation bar (with its two appearances : a large title when the view is not scrolled ; a compact appearance otherwise).
It's simple and it works...unless the view is presented with `.sheet`. At the "end of the scroll", the modal begins to lower. But if the user changes his mind... a problem with the transition between the "large" and "compact" states of the navigation bar appears.

Here is the result (iOS14/15, Simulator/Device) :

(Please click, the gif is animated)

[image]

And the code :

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
  @State private var sheet: Bool = false
   
  var body: some View {
    Button("Tap") {
      sheet.toggle()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
      NavigationView {
        ScrollView {
          Text(String(repeating: "lol ", count: 1000))
        }
        .navigationTitle("Haha")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Interesting bug. Refactoring the view didn't help. I am not sure you can do anything other than make it `.inline` the whole time and file a Radar.

Comment: I fear you are right @Yrb 
In its apps Apple rarely uses the "large title" appearance in modals.
And when it does... the bug appears (Apple Store app -> Account). So it's not because of SwiftUI.

Comment: Most likely, but it is definitely worth filing on Feedback Assistant. The more it is filed, the more likely it is to be found and fixed.